# shell script for mounting external device to mount point

Tags: shell-script, mount, usb

I want to make a script to mount an external device to a particular mount point e.g say `/mnt`. Let me elaborate my question,
suppose I run `fdisk -l` in terminal I would get this output

```
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1         493     3956672    6  FAT16
```

so I want to write a script so that when I run that script it checks for where external device is mounted(in my case sdb1) and automatically takes that partition and mount it to `/mnt`

I have scientific linux 6.4(32 bit) .

Comment: How would you know which device you want? That's not the entire `fdisk` output, you also have `sdaN`. Will it always be `sdbN`? Will it always be an external device? What else defines it? What if you have an external device with multiple partitions?

Comment: Refer this link. http://linuxconfig.org/automatically-mount-usb-external-drive-with-autofs

Answer (score 0):

I guess `udev` could help.

First you need to get serial of your device:

```
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb) | grep -i serial
```

then add the rule to /etc/udev/rules.d/

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ACTION=="add",KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{serial}=="HARDDRIVESERIAL", RUN+="/bin/mount /dev/%k /mnt/",OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

Comment: When I run "udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb) | grep -i serial"                         I got two serial numbers which one to use ?             ATTRS{serial}=="82HRQHIY"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.7"                        @dchirikov